# how to find first image in a list of images in django

Tags: html, django

I have a Django template render  result and images for search of cars. as follow:

```
{% for item in result %}
<li class="result-row">
    <!-- image box -->

<span>
<a href="#" class="result-image-act" >
    {% for image in item.images_cars_set.all %}


    {% if image.car_images_exists %}
    {% if image.car_images.0 %}
    <img   class="active" src=" {{image.car_images.url}}">
    {% endif %}
    {% if not image.car_images.0 %}
    <img    src=" {{image.car_images.url}}">
    {% endif%}
    {% endif %}
    {% empty %}

    <img  src="{% static 'path/to/default image' %}" class="active">

    {% endfor %}
</a>


<span class="embed-result-price">{{item.price}}</span>
<div class="swipe-wrap">
    <div class="swipe-wrap-lef">
        <span class="move" >
            <div class="swipe-prev">
                <p>&lt;</p>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="swipe-wrap-rig">
        <span class="move" >
            <div class="swipe-next">
                <p>&gt;</p>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>

</span>
```

The code is working fine except that I want to find the first image and put it in different img tag where it will take class="active". This class is used in javascript code to swipe all images to left or right. I tried to use  {% if image.car_images.0 %} and {% if image.car_images.first %} to find first image but not success. what I get is all images without class of active. any help or suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} do something {% endif %}` or
`{% if forloop.counter == 1 %} do something {% endif %}` to do something for the 1st item when iterating with a `{% for %}` template tag.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Thus your code should be something like

```
<a href="#" class="result-image-act" >
  {% for image in item.images_cars_set.all %}
    {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
      <img class="active" src=" {{image.car_images.url}}">
     {% else %}
       <img src=" {{image.car_images.url}}">
    {% endif %}
  {% empty %}
    <img src="{% static 'path/to/default image' %}" class="active">
  {% endfor %}
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works the way I want